# ListIndexOutOfBoundsException is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement

Tags: java, linked-list

I am creating a linkedlist program and i am getting an error that i am not sure how to fix. I know it has something to do with the try statement on my program but i need assistance on resolving this. This is my code so far.

```
public class LinkedStringTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[] array = {'L', 'u', 'k', 'e',',', ' ', 'I', ' ', 'a', 'm', ' ',
            'y', 'o', 'u', 'r', ' ', 'f', 'a', 't', 'h', 'e', 'r'};
        LinkedString s1 = new LinkedString(array);
        for(int i = 0 ; i < s1.length(); i++) {
            System.out.print(s1.charAt(i));
        }
        System.out.println();
        try {
            System.out.println(s1.charAt(20));
        }
        catch(ListIndexOutOfBoundsException e) { //* error #1
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
        System.out.println();

        LinkedString s2 = new LinkedString("Welcome, Jedi");
        for(int i = 0 ; i < s2.length(); i++) {
            System.out.print(s2.charAt(i));
        }
        System.out.println();
        try {
            System.out.println(s2.charAt(53));
        }
        catch(ListIndexOutOfBoundsException e) { //* error #2
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
        try {
            System.out.println(s1.substring(6, 35));
        }
        catch(ListIndexOutOfBoundsException e) { //* error #3
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
        try {
            System.out.println(s1.substring(10, 0));
        }
        catch(ListIndexOutOfBoundsException e) { //* error #4
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
        System.out.print("Index 0 to 16 in s1: ");
        LinkedString s3 = s1.substring(0, 16);
        for(int i = 0; i < s3.length(); i++) {
            System.out.print(s3.charAt(i));
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Index 4 to 10 in s1: ");
        s3 = s1.substring(4, 10);
        for(int i = 0; i < s3.length(); i++) {
            System.out.print(s3.charAt(i));
        }
        System.out.println();
        LinkedString s4 = s2.concat(new LinkedString(" May the force be with you."));
        for(int i = 0; i < s4.length(); i++) {
            System.out.print(s4.charAt(i));
        }
        System.out.println();
        char[] myArray = s1.toCharArray();
        for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(myArray[i]);
        }
        LinkedString s5 = new LinkedString("This is a new linked string");
        System.out.println(s5.toString());
    }
}
```

Update:
forgot to post the error. here it is.

```
LinkedStringTest.java:13: error: exception ListIndexOutOfBoundsException is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement
        catch(ListIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        ^
LinkedStringTest.java:26: error: exception ListIndexOutOfBoundsException is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement
        catch(ListIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        ^
LinkedStringTest.java:32: error: exception ListIndexOutOfBoundsException is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement
        catch(ListIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        ^
LinkedStringTest.java:38: error: exception ListIndexOutOfBoundsException is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement
        catch(ListIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        ^
4 errors
```

Comment: And add a comment in the source to identify the corresponding line number.

Answer (score 1):

`charAt()` throws an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, not a `ListIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Likewise for `substring()`.

The key is in the error message where it says:

> error: exception ListIndexOutOfBoundsException is never thrown in

This indicates that you are attempting to catch an exception that is not thrown in the try block.